# Can I join Xbox players on PC in Stardew Valley?

Tags: stardew-valley

I've got Stardew valley on PC, gotten from Game Pass on MS Store. My friend has it on his Xbox. Is it possible to join my friend?

Answer (score 2):

Multiple sources indicate the game is not cross platform in any way, including the [Wiki](https://stardewvalleywiki.com/Multiplayer):

> Crossplatform multiplayer (e.g., PS4 ↔ PC) isn't supported, except between PC versions (e.g., Windows ↔ MacOS).